# Can clients learn their time zone on a network configured using RA?

Tags: ipv6, timezone, radvd, dhcpv6

I found that there are some clients which when they are on an IPv4 network learn their current time zone through DHCP option number 101.

On an IPv6-only network where an IP prefix is advertised by `radvd` on Ubuntu Server 14.04 these clients do not pick up the correct time zone.

Is it possible to advertise time zone through `radvd` or is a DHCPv6 server required?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Stateless address autoconfiguration doesn't provide any way to transmit time zone information, but DHCPv6 does. The DHCPv4 options 100 and 101 correspond to the DHCPv6 options 41 and 42 respectively. All the gory details are in [RFC 4833](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4833).